# how do i make my contact form work?

Tags: php, forms, contact-form

The code below acts strange when I click the button on my website.

First it opens a new page where the form is again displayed but without any css or js. Then when I refill all the info and click send, it says its submitted but it wont actually sent the email.

I have tried to modify the code I am still new to php.

Code below displays and functions the contact form.

```
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    
    {
    ?>
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Your name:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Your message:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a>         again.";
        }
    else{       
        $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="Personal Plate inquiry from website";
        mail("mymail@hotmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
        }
    }  
?>
```

Comment: Is this running on an actual webserver somewhere or on a private system in your LAN?

Comment: @DuaneLortie its on an actual website

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes on your code: use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST. You can try this way:

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $name=$_POST['name'];
 $email=$_POST['email'];
 $message=$_POST['message'];
 if (($name =="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
    {
    echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a>            again.";
    }
else{       
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $subject="Personal Plate inquiry from website";
    mail("mymail@hotmail.com", $subject, $message, $from);
    echo "Email sent!";
    }
    }

   ?>
<form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
Your name:<br>
<input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your email:<br>
<input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
Your message:<br>
<textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send email"/>
</form>
```

Comment: $_REQUEST contains data of $_POST. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov, It is but don't forget, $_REQUEST is a different variable than $_GET and $_POST

Comment: @RuhulAmin i get a jist of the work behind those, but my code still doesnt work. do you think i have a problem with the server?

Comment: you have IMAP module installed for php?

Comment: @M.I.  i dont thinks so. its on a hosted webpage